# Data not stored to mysql database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

This function wont store the data to database:

```
function createJob($conn, $nameOfJob, $category, $jobDescripiton, $telephoneNumber){
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (jobName, category, description, phoneNumber, usersId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    header("location:../job.php?error=stmtfailed");
    exit();
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $nameOfJob, $category, $jobDescripiton, $telephoneNumber, $_SESSION["userid"]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
header("location:../job.php?error=none");
exit();
```

}

I have another function that checks if the fields are maybe empty, but the are not they are filled with data. I have another function to store user and it works:

```
function createUser($conn, $name, $email, $pwd){
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (usersName, usersEmail, usersPwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    header("location:../register.php?error=stmtfailed");
    exit();
}

$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $name, $email, $hashedPwd);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
header("location:../register.php?error=none");
exit();
```

}

This is the database that is NOT working:
[image]

This is the database that is working:
[image]

Comment: Check the number of fields in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Comment: Some guy who is teaching in his youtube videos  that awful practice of `header("location:../register.php?error=stmtfailed");` instead of proper error reporting did more harm to the language than anyone else.

Comment: Well when your are beginner it`s hard to tell what is a good practice and what isn`t